# is it possible log4net writes things out of order in a multithreaded app

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a multithreaded C# app for which we use common.logging/log4net. while the logs read reasonably as one would expect, the timestamps can be pretty far off. I'm questioning if I can trust what I see, in terms of order of operations.

In this case I'm tracking memory and resetting my ConsumerUI. In the T09:27 entry I have lots of memory, in the next entry, T04:27 I don't.  But you'll notice the T04 timestamp precedes the prior log entry by like 5 hours.

I've added diagnostic code to see if the log statements are truly out of order they are not.  A timestamp arrives that is simply wrong.

What is going on here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of appender is creating that output? Is there only a single process logging? What is the log4net locking strategy (if a file appender)?

Comment: I've added the appender to question. Minimal lock.

Comment: No forwarding appenders configured?

Comment: at root there, is a debug appender and this rollinglogfile appender that's it. both out of the box appenders.

Comment: Honestly you shouldn't care.  Logging is pure data, just like any data source if you need to sort it then sort it when you need to present it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All logging is Async. Its up to the log reader to correllate a coherent time sequence from the log files written. If this wasnt the case, logging would impost a hideous syncblock on an otherwise multithreaded application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your log target configuration, the order of logged operations may be very far off. Typically for DB, file, or other expensive IO logging targets, a buffering Async wrapper is used, which will write to the IO target in batches, depending on usage. So it is fairly common to have the order that they get flushed not match the order that they were logged.

We always order our logs by the dateLoggedUTC (our field for that date) in order to really understand the order of operations.

Comment: when you say order by dateLoggedUTC, is that something I can set in the config file?

Comment: %utcdate{ABSOLUTE} is what we use. And our records are in a DB, not a text file

Comment: Indeed, the time difference is very close to 5 hours. Could really by a time zone thing.